# Student Badge not awarded for the first question asked

Tags: support, badges

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [Select distinct values from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49323818/select-distinct-values-from-a-string)

I had asked my first question on Stack Overflow back in March 2018 and had received an answer as well (which I did not acknowledge that time).
Going through my profile today I noticed that am yet to earn the Student badge.
It would be helpful to understand why my first question was not counted then itself, given this badge does not have any other requirement.

[image]

Comment: _"First question with score of 1 or more"_. Your question currently sits at a score of 0.

Comment: @n8te, you beat me to it! I just noticed that. Thanks anyhow :)
My next question would be, how are scores counted/determined?

Comment: @AshishSingh To help you find your own answers to many badge related questions, the following post is very helpful: [What are the badges I can earn, and what are the exact criteria for earning each badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397/363946). Although they don't define how scores are counted, so I'll explain that for you. Scores are defined by the number of votes on a post. People who upvote the post increase the score by 1, and people who downvote the post decrease it by 1. Your question has 0 upvotes and 0 downvotes, so the score is zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that your question does have a score of 1 (because somebody upvoted it), you did earn a [Student badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2/student?userid=8692106).

[image]

Comment: Yes, I noticed that @Glorfindel. Thanks!